# How to remove elements from the DOM if they are consecutive

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath

I inherited the following piece of PHP code, that removes elements from the DOM before pushing the content into a page. We only want to show the first 5 elements to not have a too long page

Assuming the code retrieves an HTML fragment structured like this:

```html
<div class='year'>2019</div>
<div class='record'>Record A</div>
<div class='record'>Record B</div>
<div class='year'>2018</div>
<div class='record'>Record C</div>
<div class='record'>Record D</div>
<div class='record'>Record E</div>
<div class='year'>2017</div>
<div class='record'>Record F</div>
<div class='year'>2016</div>
<div class='record'>Record G</div>
```

Now, the below piece of code removes all the extra `records`:

```php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
// be sure to load the encoding
$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $tmp);
// let's use XPath
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
// set the limit
$limit = 5; $cnt = 0;
// and remove unwanted elements
foreach($finder->query("//*[contains(@class, 'record')]") as $elm ) {
    if ($cnt >= $limit)
        $elm->parentNode->removeChild($elm);
        $cnt++;
    }
// finally, echo
echo $dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement);
```

Logically, I end up having the following HTML:

```html
<div class='year'>2019</div>
<div class='record'>Record A</div>
<div class='record'>Record B</div>
<div class='year'>2018</div>
<div class='record'>Record C</div>
<div class='record'>Record D</div>
<div class='record'>Record E</div>
<div class='year'>2017</div>
<div class='year'>2016</div>
```

How could I identify all the elements having the class `year` and having the next sibling also having this class and delete it? (here that would get the 2017 element)

Then I believe it would only be a matter of checking if the last element has the class `year` and remove it.

Or is there a cleaner way to achieve that?

Comment: It is not clear what the rules are here. Why are Record F and G special?

Comment: @mplungjan We only want to display the first 5 elements (records). Otherwise, the page would be too long.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an extra foreach after the current one...

```
foreach($finder->query("//div[@class='year']/following-sibling::div[1][@class='year']") 
        as $elm ) {
    $elm->parentNode->removeChild($elm);
}
```

The XPath here is looking for a `<div class="year">` element and then only looking at the next `<div>` tag for the same thing (`following-sibling::div[1]` limits it to just the next div tag after the current one).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plain JS method in case you want to do this on the client instead

```js
const recs = document.querySelectorAll(".record");
const divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
const lastRec = recs[4];
let found = false;
divs.forEach(div => {
  div.classList.toggle("hide",found)
  if (div === lastRec) found = true
})
```

```css
.hide { display:none}
```

```html
<div class='year'>2019</div>
<div class='record'>Record A</div>
<div class='record'>Record B</div>
<div class='year'>2018</div>
<div class='record'>Record C</div>
<div class='record'>Record D</div>
<div class='record'>Record E</div>
<div class='year'>2017</div>
<div class='record'>Record F</div>
<div class='year'>2016</div>
<div class='record'>Record G</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up using the following code:

```php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
// be sure to load the encoding
$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $tmp);
// let's use XPath
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
foreach($finder->query("(//*[contains(@class, 'record')])[5]/following-sibling::*") as $elm) {
    $elm->parentNode->removeChild($elm);
    }
// finally, echo
echo $dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement);
```

it allowed me to achieve my goal in 1 pass without using nested loops